# How to make a VideoView Preview UI in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm a beginner in android and I've been trying to experiment media related elements of Android. So far, I was able to display video, but I saw Viber and some other similar apps have some slick way of displaying video like below, wherein when tapped will open an app viewer wherein images/videos of app can be seen there:

[image]

Here is my code, it starts video immediately... I tried the `.seekTo(100)`, .`.seekTo(0)` option but both gives me a black screen.

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mVideoFileName);
        mVideoMessageView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mediaC.setAnchorView(mVideoMessageView);
        mVideoMessageView.start();
```

I wonder, how they made an overlay of a play button on the video, duration, and even timestamp and have a snapshot of it. Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int id = **"The Video's ID"**
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id,     MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

Also you can use Glide for this

```
Glide  
.with( context )
.load( Uri.fromFile( new File( filePath ) ) )
.into( imageViewGifAsBitmap );
```

Comment: thanks for introducing me to Glide... I didn't know that :) Wooah!